# Responsive design, Positioning elements?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create text elements that are stuck together. When you resize the window the elements maintain the same position relative to each other. For instance, in the example below C stays under P. If I used a wrapper the site won't work with multiple browser sizes. Is there a way to put it in a fixed place where it moves along with the window?

Here is an example: (Chris Carpenter) (creative design)
http://chris-carpenter.co.uk/

Is it possible to do this with jQuery?

```
.creative {
text-align: center;
font-size: 40px;
color: #dce0df;
font-family: brush;
}


.chris {
text-align: center;
font-family: helv2;
font-size: 72px;
line-height: 300px;
}
```

This might explain it a little better

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iM8r6.jpg

So i want the position of both text elements to stay the same in relation to eachother when you resize the windows.

Comment: Please include the relevant code within your question.

Comment: Sorry, reletively new here, is that right?

Comment: Heya, welcome to SO! It's great that you edited your question to improve it, this will automatically nominate it for reopening. I've not yet voted as such yet, because IMO you may need to include a more complete repro (include some markup inside the question itself) as well as some details on the things you've tried. Use [this checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) if you're unsure about how to improve.

Comment: I've updated the OP again with an image that helps explain it a little better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with CSS 2.

Is this what you are trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/W5tzs/2/

First move creative into chris:

```
<p class="chris">CHRIS CARPENTER<p class="creative">Creative Design</p></p>
```

Then add relative positioning to creative:

```
.creative {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: -110px;
    left: 100px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #dce0df;        
}
```

Adjust top and left to your heart's content. Use a media query if you need creative to shift when chris word wraps. Add a min-width if it bothers you that creative moves when the window is really small.

Comment: Sadly this did not give the desired effect. I added on an image to my OP, it explains the issue a little more.

Comment: Ah, just use relative positioning and move creative into chris. I've updated my answer.

Comment: This worked a treat thank you so much. I dont understand why it was moving when I was using left: 100px; before?